# Trying to create a chessboard using an array and graphics

Tags: java, arrays, graphics

Not gonna lie, this is a homework problem.  Thing is, we haven't gone over graphics in detail yet, just through an example.

I'm not sure what is wrong with my program.  Everything seems to check out, but the window that pops up doesn't display what I'm trying to create.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
public class ProblemR6_37
{
  public static void draw(Graphics g)
  {
    int[][] values=new int[8][8];
    for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++)
    {
      for (int j=0; j<values[i].length; j++)
      {
        if ((i+j)%2!=0)
        {values[i][j]=1;}
      }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<values.length; i++)
    {
      for (int j=0; j<values[i].length; i++)
      {
        if (values[i][j]==0)
        {
          g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
          g.fillRect(j*20, i*20, 20,20);
        }
        else if (values[i][j]==1)
        {
          g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
          g.fillRect(j*20,i*20,20,20);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JComponent component=new JComponent()
    {
      public void paintComponent(Graphics graph)
      {
        draw(graph);
      }
    };
    frame.add(component);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Most of the graphics items are pulled straight from the example.

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: `"...doesn't display what I'm trying to create"` -- which you *haven't* told us! Please fix this.

Comment: Change the second inner loop increment from `i++` to `j++`. Good luck!

Comment: And if you're seeing errors or exceptions -- you should tell us that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one problem in your code:

Change `for (int j=0; j<values[i].length; i++)` to `for (int j=0; j<values[i].length; j++)`

You put `i++` instead of `j++`.

Comment: I feel really dumb right now.  Should have been more attentive to that.  Sorry